# /bin/bash failing "-r" operator, but it works in /bin/sh

Tags: bash, docker, alpine-linux

A bash script that has always been running as a container entry point. I just upgraded from Alpine3.13 to Alpine3.15.0 and the script started failing the "-r" checks on mounted AND unmounted files.
Docker version `18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a`
libseccomp version `libseccomp2/now 2.4.1-0ubuntu0.18.04.2`

Minimum example

```
bash-5.1# ls -lt try
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 24 08:47 try

bash-5.1# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -r /tmp/try ] ; then
    echo "fail -r"
fi

if [ ! -f /tmp/try ] ; then
    echo "fail -f"
fi

bash-5.1# bash test.sh
fail -r
bash-5.1# sh test.sh
bash-5.1#
```

Comment: I can't repro in Docker `alpine:latest`, Bash 5.1.16-r0

Comment: Yeah I also tried to deploy on a different env, same dockerfile, image, and script. And it works as expected. I'm mainly wondering what may have happened here and how one may try and find out. Bash 5.1.16-40 as well

Comment: If it's not reproducible with the information in the question, I'm afraid there is nothing we can do to solve the problem. I'm vaguely thinking you are probably _actually_ checking mount points or volumes mounted in Docker, but without details about this, I would be tempted to vote to close this as unreproducible.

Comment: In the example above, it's a container without any mounted volumes. A simple `touch /tmp/try` and the snippet above follows

Comment: Perhaps delete this for now, and [edit] and undelete once you have more details?

Comment: Re-opened and edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been documented here: https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/issues/156

The suggested solutions are listed here: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.14.0#faccessat2

As I am unable to update docker and libseccomp version, I've tried the 3rd option and worked alright

> 3. As a workaround, in order to run under old Docker or libseccomp versions, the [moby default seccomp profile](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/seccomp/default.json) should be downloaded and on line 2, `defaultAction` changed to `SCMP_ACT_TRACE`, then `--seccomp-profile=default.json` can be passed to dockerd, or `--security-opt=seccomp=default.json` passed to `docker create` or `docker run`. This will cause the system calls to return ENOSYS instead of EPERM, allowing the container to fall back to faccessat.